# How to replace a string after particular string in a text?

Tags: java

I am looking for an elegant way to replace a string after a particular word in a text with  Java.
Example:
"Today we have an IKAR ME123 from Greece."
I want to replace the word after "IKAR" with my custom string, lets say XXXX , then the text should look:
"Today we have an IKAR XXXX from Greece."
Is there a nice way of doing it ,without have to write some ugly regular expression or 200 lines of code ?I've looked on Stackoverflow , and even though i found "similar" questions , non adressed that particular situation !

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a reasonable place to use a regex.

Comment: Why should a regular expression be ugly? `IKAR \w+` is succinct and understable.

Comment: @knittl i tried replaceAll("IKAR \\w+", "XXXX") ,is that what you mean ?

Comment: @user2557930 if you want to keep the "IKAR" part, you need to replace with "IKAR XXXX".

Answer (score 1):

```
"Today we have an IKAR ME123 from Greece."
  .replaceFirst("IKAR \\w+","IKAR XXXX");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReplaceText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Today we have an IKAR ME123 from Greece";
        String replacement = "XXXX";
        System.out.println( replaceBetween( input, "IKAR ", " from", replacement ) );
    }

    private static String replaceBetween( String input, String start, String end, String replacement ) {
        return input.substring( 0, input.lastIndexOf( start ) + start.length() ) + replacement + input.substring( input.lastIndexOf( end ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, thank for the code, but it assumes we know the end word, and thats not the case.I only gave the string as an illustrative purpose, i need the word after IKAR replaced, regardless of the next word after that !

Comment: Then you'll need to be very specific about how you define a word. Is it anything with a space after it? Hyphen? Period?

Comment: yes it is with space

Comment: OK, it should be pretty easy using what I've already posted to modify the code to work with a space after the word. Hint: indexOf() will get you there.